# About uniform continuity of function on unbounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. If $f$ is uniform continuous on $[k,\infty)$  for some $k$ then $f$ is uniform continuous on $[0,\infty)$
 I start proof as:
Now f is uniform continuous on $[K,\infty)$ and also on $[0,k+1]$. 
So we get the following for $ \epsilon>0$:
[image]

When I tried it myself I took $\delta= \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$  why do we take 1 in this set not able to understand? Please help me.

Comment: We need $\delta\leqslant1$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta$, then both $x$ and $y$ lie in either $[k,\infty)$ or $[0,k+1]$. Consider what would happen if $\delta_{1},\delta_{2}$ were larger than 1, say $\delta_{1}=\delta_{2}=2$. Now suppose $x=k-1/3$ and $y=k+1+1/3$. We can't say anything about $|f(x)-f(y)|$ despite the fact that $|x-y|<2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need that $x,y$ are both in $[0,k+\color{red}1]$ or both in $[k,\infty)$. You can conclude this only if $|x-y|\le 1$.

Alternatively, you might have worked with $[0,k+\delta_1]$ instead of $[0,k+1]$.